# How do I share object from main file to supporting file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, share

I have something similar.

```
# MAIN.RB
require 'sockets'
require_relative 'replies.rb'
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 6500
s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
$connected = 0
while line = s.gets   # Read lines from the socket
#DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
if line == "Hi"
reply line
end
end
s.close
```

Then I have the reply function in a secondary file.

```
# REPLIES.RB

def reply(input)
if input == "Hi"
    s.write("Hello my friend.\n"
end    
end
```

However calling on the object s from the second file does not seem to work. How would I go about making this work. I'm new to Ruby. I've searched google for the answer, but the only results I have found is with sharing variables across files. I could always do a return "Hello my friend.\n", but I rather be able to write to the socket object directly from the function in REPLIES.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that variables are strictly local unless you expressly pass them in. This means `s` only exists in the `main` context. You can fix this by passing it in:

```
reply(s, line)
```

And on the receiving side:

```
def reply(s, input)
  # ...
end
```

I'd **strongly** encourage you to try and indent things consistently here, this code is really out of sorts, and avoid using global variables like `$connected`. Using a simple self-contained class you could clean up this code considerably.

Also, don't add `.rb` extensions when calling `require`. It's implied.

Comment: I do apologize for the indentation. I was typing merely from memory, so didn't have exact code infront of me. Thank you for your help. I didn't know about passing the object in that manner but now I do so it will make other things so much easier as I learn new and interesting things in Ruby. Also didn't know the .rb was implied, so that is useful information as well. Thanks.

Comment: No trouble. Just mentioning these things so you can avoid pitfalls in the future. Ruby is generally pretty forgiving but there are some things it can't deal with, and it's also easy to get so complacent your code becomes unmaintainable. Hope that got it working.

Comment: Got it working smashingly well. Now on to the the next mountain. After 24 hours of dabbling with ruby I've come to the the realization that I should have attempted it years ago.

Comment: Don't forget to check the answers that work for you. I can see a number in your history that look like they were solved but credit was never given. Helps others in the same jam find questions that were successfully answered.